# Elasticsearch : map date as text?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have json data that has a "product_ref" field that can take these values as an example:

```
"product_ref": "N/A"
"product_ref": "90323"
"product_ref": "SN3005"
"product_ref": "2015-05-23"
```

When pushing the data to the index i get a mapping error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [root.product_ref] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [text]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [root.product_ref] of different type, current_type [date], merged_type [text]"},"status":400}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Do you have any other date-fields for this type in your index?

Comment: I've got 5 fields mapped as text and one mapped to long.

Comment: Please try out the edited version of my answer. I tested with elasticsearch 6 and it works. (Some feedback if it worked for you, would be great)

Comment: I've got elasticsearch 5.4.3 and it threw the same error.

Comment: well, it is supported for this version,too. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/dynamic-field-mapping.html. Maybe you missed something. Could you please post your index mappings? You can do that with a GET /"your_index_name" . you should be able to see something like the following: {
  "product": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "test": {
        "date_detection": false,
        "properties": {
          "product_ref": {
            "type": "keyword"

Comment: Here is my index mappings:
"mappings":{"doc":{"date_detection":false,"properties":{"product_brand":{"type":"text"},"product_category":{"type":"text"},"product_link":{"type":"text"},"product_name":{"type":"text"},"product_price":{"type":"long"},"product_ref":{"type":"keyword"},"product_seller":{"type":"text"}}}}...

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou I'm gonna accept your answer.

Comment: Did you make it? Your mappings look correct.  I would choose another name for the type in the index though.  Doc ist used by Elasticsearch itself.

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou That was it. A rookie mistake. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is something called [date detection](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html), and by default, it is  enabled.

> If date_detection is enabled (default), then new string fields are checked to see whether their contents match any of the date patterns specified in dynamic_date_formats. If a match is found, a new date field is added with the corresponding format.

You just need to disable it by modifying your mappings:

```
 PUT /products    

 {
  "mappings": {
     "doc": { 
        "date_detection": false, 
        "properties": { 
           "product_ref": { "type": "keyword"  }, 

         }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: I'm already mapping 'product-ref' as text yet I'm having the error.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because ElasticSearch assumed you're indexing dates of a particular format, and a value which doesn't match that was attempted to be indexed. i.e. after indexing date, you index wrong format.

Make sure all the values are dates and none are empty,perhaps remove these in your ingestion layer.

EDIT: If you don't care to lose the date value you can use the [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html).

```
{
    "dynamic_templates": [
        {
            "integers": {
                "match_mapping_type": "date",
                "mapping": {
                    "type": "text"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't want to remove them. I just want to keep them as texts..Is that possible?